# Best way to store multiple boolean valued columns in Mysql table?

Tags: mysql, boolean

I have Table called "hotel_rooms" which looks like this:

```
id <- int
name <- string
description <- string
max_people <- int
```

I need to store multiple boolean values inside of table (Internet,Air conditioner, Sea View, TV, Cable TV, Desk, Baby bed,Kitchen, Cooker).

Should I store them all independently like

```
id <- int
name <- string
description <- string
max_people <- int
Internet <- boolean
air_conditioner <- boolean
sea_view <- boolean
tv <- boolean
...........
```

Or is there some better way.

Comment: Use an attribute-value table, since the attributes will likely change over time.

Comment: Use a `SET` of `ENUM` in a single column.